# How to run php script via exec in c ++ process and get std :: out from this script?

Tags: php, c++, linux

I have a C ++ program, it requires the output of a php script. I tried to run it through execlp but I failed ... execlp returns -1. Please tell me what I could indicate incorrectly, and will this method of reading std :: out from the child process work?

this code does not work:

```
int main()
{
    int p[2];
    if (pipe(p) < 0)
        return -1;

    pid_t child = fork();

    if(child < 0)
        return -1;
    else if (child == 0)
    {
        close(p[0]);
        dup2(p[1], 1);
        execlp("php7.2", "/home/anton/test.php");
        close(p[1]);
        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else{
        close(p[1]);
        char buf[256] = "";
        read(p[0], &buf, 256);
        close(p[0]);
        printf("Child output:\n%s\n", buf);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Comment: According to the docs, -1 is the return value for any failure, and the error code is stored in `errno`. What is the value of `errno` after the failure?

Comment: Nothing gets executed after `exec` statements.

Comment: @Kostas https://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp - "The exec() functions only return if an error has occurred"

Comment: @Kostas unless `exec` fails (which makes it ironic that they return `EXIT_SUCCESS`).

Comment: errno = 14. 
Added NULL 3 argument, the process just started to hang